# How to evaluate a Hamiltonian (Quantum Mechanics) in Python

Tags: python, physics

I'm working on this project where I've been tasked to model the band structure of various potentials, I've worked through all of the math on paper and have had success hard coding some results, but I'm looking to be able to produce results from scratch providing only the eigenvector, Hamiltonian, and potential being explored, I'm working in Python by the way.

So far I've been able to represent the components of my Hamiltonian that are just dependent on the (-h_bar^2/2m)*(d^2/dx^2). I'm using Numpy to represent my bra's as arrays and then using Numpy's inner product function to evaluate the components of my Hamiltonian that are just dependent on the second derivative and its respective constants. Issues arise when I go to try and evaluate the components of the Hamiltonian that are potential dependent (seeing that the full Hamiltonian operator is (-h_bar^2/2m)*(d^2/dx^2) + V(x)).

I'm not quite sure how to complete this part. I've tried evaluating the inner product in its integral form using SciPy, but I keep running into issues when trying to evaluate these integrals that have complex components (SciPy doesn't like that).

To get a more solid idea of what I'm doing, here's the PDF I'm working out of:https://era.library.ualberta.ca/items/4835014b-1dbc-48e1-bbec-c175c87c9b03/view/000b36c4-55ba-471b-aaf8-d9d1c5f5ee06/Pavelich_Robert_L_201609_MSc.pdf (page 19-22 as written in the actual document)

Any help would be much appreciated, I'm fairly new to Quantum Mechanics as a whole and even greener when it comes to modeling it. Thanks a lot!

Comment: Please post some code so we can offer actual help

Comment: Can you split the integrals that you are trying to compute into real and imaginary parts, integrate each numerically with SciPy and then put them back together. After all, the potential is a real-valued function and the basis functions are the trigonometric exponentials, so you can split them into cos and sin by Euler's decomposition.

Answer (score 0):

The other way to compute Hamiltonian with your given Potential can be evaluated using Finite difference method where you can diagonalize your Hamiltonian and calculate eigen value and eigen states, Therefore could obtain the spectrum .
This code might be helpful https://github.com/mholtrop/QMPython/blob/master/Finite%20Well%20Bound%20States.ipynb